# Understanding $a\vec b * \nabla c$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, differential-operators

I have some difficulties when working with nabla-operators and I might need advice.

Is it correct to say that
$$a\vec b \cdot \nabla c = a\nabla \cdot (\vec bc) + ac\nabla \cdot \vec b~~~?$$

If so, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The expression $a \vec{b} \nabla c$ is ambiguous. $a\vec{b}$ and $\nabla c$ are both vector quantities. In this question are you using juxtaposition of vectors to imply the scalar 'dot' product? Further $\nabla \vec{b}$ is ambiguous as well. Does this imply the divergence of $\vec{b}$?

Comment: It seems that $\nabla$ is not the same everywhere if $b$ is a vector. Maybe to make sense out out this operator try to compute it in easy case for function or vector field you chose. Then try to fix $a, b,$ and $c$ and see if your formula holds.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity - I updated the equation

Comment: This is still potentially ambiguous. Setting aside the unambiguous $a$, we can either read this as $\vec{b}\cdot (\nabla c)$ (i.e., the scalar product of $\vec{b}$ and the gradient) or as $(\vec{b}\cdot \nabla)c$ (i.e., the directional derivative of $c$ along $\vec{b}$). Without other context, I would read $\vec{b}\cdot \nabla c$ as the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two functions $c:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $b:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ you can compute $\nabla \cdot (b(x)c(x))$ to be
\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot (b(x)c(x)) &= \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(b_i(x)c(x)) = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(b_i(x))c(x)+b_i(x)\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}c(x)\right)\\
&= c(x)\left(\nabla \cdot b(x)\right)+b(x)\cdot \nabla c(x)
\end{align*}
Thus your formula should be
$$a b \cdot (\nabla c) = a\nabla \cdot (bc)-ac \nabla \cdot b$$
with $b,c$ as above and $a:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary.